# difference between /proc/self/mountstats vs /proc/self/mountinfo vs /proc/self/mounts

Tags: linux, debian, mount

I'm reading `/proc/self/mountstats` on a debian machine to identify if the usb devices is mounted or not. (`mountstats` because it better in term of readability)

But I also see `/proc/self/mountinfo` and `/proc/self/mounts`

What I would like to understand what essentially is the difference between each of the three files. the man page of [mountstats](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mountstats.8.html) Displays various NFS client per-mount statistics.

Does that also means that `mountinfo` and `mounts` does not display NFS client. In past I have seen `mounts` does display NFS details (If remember correctly)